# StampedLock#tryOptimisticRead() implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm implementing a cache read or load method with **`StampedLock`** and I'm wondering if I can adapt the examples from the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/StampedLock.html) better than this.

The author Doug Lea has given an 'optimistic read' example and an 'upgrade read lock to write lock' example, but in my use case I want to do both together.

```
public String getConverted(String input) {

    String customised = null;
    long stamp = 0L;

    while (customised == null) {
        if (!lock.validate(stamp)) {
            stamp = lock.tryOptimisticRead();
        }
        customised = cached.get(input);

        // if the lock was valid we can trust the value of customised
        if (lock.validate(stamp) && customised == null) {
            long writeStamp = 0L;
            try {
                while (customised == null) {
                    writeStamp = lock.tryConvertToWriteLock(stamp);
                    if (writeStamp != 0L) {
                        stamp = writeStamp;
                        customised = convertToCustom(input);
                        cached.put(input, customised);
                    } else {

                        // so what do we do here (line 15)?

                    }
                }
            } finally {
                lock.unlock(stamp);
            }
        } else {
            // if the lock was invalid, customised could be anything, so:
            customised = null;

            // and what do we do here (line 25)?
        }
    }

    return customised;
}
```

So there are two points in the algorithm where I need to do something - in both cases either:

1. Obtain the hard lock - at line 15:

   ```
                       lock.unlockRead(stamp);
                       stamp = lock.writeLock();
   ```

   and at line 25:

   ```
                       stamp = lock.readLock();
   ```
2. Or what?

   ```
                       Thread.sleep(25);
   ```

which doesn't cut it for me - surely `StampedLock` can do a better job of managing the blocking on this thread!

But how? If I just call `readLock()` or `writeLock()` then I give up the hopefully well coded and tested queueing algorithms inside `StampedLock#tryOptimisticRead()` and `StampedLock#tryConvertToWriteLock()`.

Or is the logic behind those methods already forfeited because they failed once?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at following methods for reference.

**There is no queueing mechanism in tryConvertToWriteLock and tryOptimisticRead.**

> Method tryOptimisticRead() returns a non-zero stamp only if the lock
>   is not currently held in write mode. Method validate(long) returns
>   true if the lock has not been acquired in write mode since obtaining a
>   given stamp. This mode can be thought of as an extremely weak version
>   of a read-lock, that can be broken by a writer at any time. The use of
>   optimistic mode for short read-only code segments often reduces
>   contention and improves throughput. However, its use is inherently
>   fragile. Optimistic read sections should only read fields and hold
>   them in local variables for later use after validation. Fields read
>   while in optimistic mode may be wildly inconsistent, so usage applies
>   only when you are familiar enough with data representations to check
>   consistency and/or repeatedly invoke method validate(). For example,
>   such steps are typically required when first reading an object or
>   array reference, and then accessing one of its fields, elements or
>   methods.

Also, I like the control flow where you check validity of optimistic locking and if you find it to be invalid then acquire lock as it avoids the need of "else" block as used in your code.

Similar code flow for **tryConvertToWriteLock**.

```
private final StampedLock sl = new StampedLock(); 

    /**


    * This method is to show the feature of tryOptimisticRead() method  
    */ 
      public double getTotalRevenueOptimisticRead() {  
        long stamp = sl.tryOptimisticRead();  
        double balance = this.totalRevenue;
        boolean lockAcquired = false;   
        //calling validate(stamp) method to ensure that stamp is valid, if not then acquiring the read lock  
        if (!sl.validate(stamp)){
          lockAcquired = true;   
          LOG.info("stamp for tryOptimisticRead() is not valid now, so acquiring the read lock");   
          stamp = sl.readLock();  
        }     
        try {    
          balance = this.totalRevenue;   
        } finally {
          if(lockAcquired){
             sl.unlockRead(stamp); 
          }    
        }  
        return balance; 
      } 



/**  
* This method is to show the feature of tryConvertToWriteLock() method  
*/ 
  public double getStateTaxReturnUisngConvertToWriteLock(TaxPayer taxPayer) { 
    double incomeTaxRetunAmount = taxPayer.getTaxAmount() * 5/100;  
    long stamp = sl.readLock();
    boolean lockAcquired = false;     
    //Trying to upgrade the lock from read to write  
    stamp = sl.tryConvertToWriteLock(stamp);    
    //Checking if tryConvertToWriteLock got success otherwise call writeLock method  
    if(stamp == 0L){   
      LOG.info("stamp is zero for tryConvertToWriteLock(), so acquiring the write lock");   
      stamp = sl.writeLock();
      lockAcquired = true;  
    }    
    try {   
      this.totalRevenue -= incomeTaxRetunAmount;  
    } finally {
      if(lockAcquired){
         sl.unlockWrite(stamp);
      }   
    }  
    return incomeTaxRetunAmount; 
  }
```

Comment: It's because I'm trying to combine them that the control flow in my example is not straightforward. I like the control flow in your examples too, but sadly they don't help :(

Comment: Your example code is wrong. You are establishing a lock inside an `if` block but unlocking it completely outside the `if` block.

Comment: @Gili Thank you so much for pointing out the mistake. Let me know if current edit using a boolean lockAcquired makes sense or there is any better way.